# Looking for free online webservice for getting zipcode(/postalcode) from lat, long?

Tags: iphone

I am Looking for free online webservice for getting zipcode(/postalcode) from lat, long ?

There is one :

http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesxml?formatted=true&lat=latValue&lng=longValue

but its not working.....!

Do you know other than this...?

Thanks

Comment: What you want is a Reverse Geocoding service: http://www.google.com/search?q=Reverse-Geocoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question is tagged iPhone, I assume you're doing this on the iPhone. If that's the case, why not just use MapKit?

Use the MKReverseGeocoder class which, given your latitude/longitude pair, will send `-reverseGeocoder:didFindPlaceMark:` to its delegate. The placemark has a `postalCode` property.

If you really need a web service, I've looked at the following services for *geocoding* (not reverse-geocoding). You might want to look at them to see if any of them suits your needs:

- [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
- [CloudMade](http://blog.cloudmade.com/2009/06/12/how-to-get-forward-geocoding-in-iphone-mapkit/)
- [Tiny Geocoder](http://tinygeocoder.com/)
- [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html)
- [TeleAtlas](http://www.geocode.com/) (not purely a web service)

I've done limited testing of each of these services with the exception of TeleAtlas. For my purposes, Google and Tiny Geocoder returned the best results. YMMV.

Comment: I know that but MKReverseGeocoder not accurate.

Comment: I have also found that sometimes i am not getting postalCode value while working with reverseGeocoder:didFindPlaceMark:

Comment: Matrix: My understanding is MKReverseGeocoder uses Google Maps data, so it's as accurate as Google is.

Answer (score 0):

CloudMade supports reverse geocoding...